# Check if checked multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have one input where if his value is higher than 32 I display a button where on click display a modal with 3 tables where on each row checkboxes, and I want to validate if is not checked do block user to click on save button, here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var vals = $('.valtotal').val();
  if (vals > 32) {
    $('.post-abs').show();
  
  } else {
    $('.post-abs').hide();

  }

})

function toggle1(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel1[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle2(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel2[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle3(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel3[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle4(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel4[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle5(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel5[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle6(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel6[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle7(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel7[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle8(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel8[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle11(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel11[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle22(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel22[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle33(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel33[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle44(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel44[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle55(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel55[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle66(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel66[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle77(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel77[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle88(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel88[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle111(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel111[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle222(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel222[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle333(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel333[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle444(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel444[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle555(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel555[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle666(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel666[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle777(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel777[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function toggle888(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('caiet_tabel888[]');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="34" class="valtotal">

<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="post-abs btn btn-primary float-left"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Multiple</button>
<div class="container-fluid">

<button class="btn-save">Save button</button>

  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg custom-modal">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form class="">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Multiple caiete de tipar</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="nr_caiet">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="titlu-caiet">
                      Nr pag Caietul 1
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bife_caiet">
                  <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Toate </th>
                        <th scope="col">C</th>
                        <th scope="col">M</th>
                        <th scope="col">Y </th>
                        <th scope="col">K</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T1F1</th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle1(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel1[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel1[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel1[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel1[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T1F2</th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle2(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel2[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel2[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel2[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel2[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T2F1 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle3(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel3[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel3[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel3[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel3[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T2F2 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle4(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel4[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel4[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel4[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel4[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T3F1 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle5(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel5[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel5[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel5[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel5[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T3F2 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle6(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel6[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel6[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel6[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel6[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T4F1 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle7(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel7[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel7[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel7[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel7[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T4F2 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle8(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel8[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel8[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel8[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel8[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="nr_caiet">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="titlu-caiet">
                      Nr pag Caietul 2
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bife_caiet">
                  <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Toate </th>
                        <th scope="col">C</th>
                        <th scope="col">M</th>
                        <th scope="col">Y </th>
                        <th scope="col">K</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T1F1</th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle11(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel11[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel11[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel11[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel11[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T1F2</th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle22(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel22[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel22[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel22[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel22[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T2F1 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle33(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel33[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel33[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel33[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel33[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T2F2 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle44(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel44[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel44[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel44[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel44[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T3F1 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle55(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel55[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel55[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel55[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel55[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T3F2 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle66(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel66[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel66[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel66[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel66[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T4F1 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle77(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel77[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel77[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel77[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel77[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T4F2 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle88(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel88[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel88[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel88[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel88[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="nr_caiet">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="titlu-caiet">
                      Nr pag Caietul 2
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bife_caiet">
                  <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Toate </th>
                        <th scope="col">C</th>
                        <th scope="col">M</th>
                        <th scope="col">Y </th>
                        <th scope="col">K</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T1F1</th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle111(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel111[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel111[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel111[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel111[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T1F2</th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle222(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel222[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel222[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel222[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel222[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T2F1 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle333(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel333[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel333[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel333[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel333[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T2F2 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle444(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel444[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel444[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel444[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel444[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T3F1 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle555(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel555[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel555[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel555[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel555[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T3F2 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle666(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel666[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel666[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel666[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel666[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T4F1 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle777(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel777[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel777[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel777[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel777[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">T4F2 </th>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle888(this)"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel888[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel888[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel888[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="caiet_tabel888[]"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Inchide</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <button type="button" value="insert" class="btn btn-success float-right">Salveaza</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So what i need is if value is greater than 32 display button for modal and validation for each checkbox but not for the checkbox who if is checked check all checkboxes from his line.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want. I see your modal window, I see your checkboxes. What next? What should be done with this checkboxes? Or what? Use commas and dots in your explanations please.

Answer (score 0):

As has been indicated in the comments, it is quite difficult to grasp exactly what your validation entails. What I understand is that once the value in the input with class `valtotal` is greater than 32, a button needs to appear which initializes a modal. You can achieve that with something like this using jquery:

```
$(".valtotal").on("keyup", function(){
   if($(".valtotal").val() >32  ){
      $('.post-abs').show();                 
   } else {
      $('.post-abs').hide();
   }                
});
```

Similarly, to check whether a particular checkbox has been checked you can do something similar:

```
$('#theCheckBoxId').change(function(){
   if($('#theCheckBoxId').is(':checked')) {
     //Disable the save button
     $("#saveButtonId").prop("disabled", false);
   } else {
     $("#saveButtonId").prop("disabled", true);
   }
});
```

If you need a better explanation, try and be more specific regarding your validation

Comment: Thank, what i am trying to do is if value is greater than 32 display modal button and start validation of checkboxes if is not 32 just hide that button, but i i will try to do what you did, thank you sir and have a nice day!